# Using singleton class in multi thread situation and be thread safe! (best practice and best performance)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I need a solution for my project.
I have a library which it is using java socket to send and receive message. I know it is not thread safe.
I created a singleton class(B) with a method called xxx. In this method I invoke send method of library. library have another method called receive. Then I invoke receive method of library and get response. when I used it in multi thread mode requests and responses don't match properly. 
I know I can use synchronized for my xxx method to make it thread safe. But I'm searching for a solution that be best practice and have best performance.
I think I should have another module for matching requests and responses without have to use synchronized keyword for xxx method. 
I'm eager to read your suggestions. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can use Enum for singleton.

Comment: Could you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum B {
    INSTANCE;

    //xxx method.
}
```

You can define singleton class through an enum having only one instance and this will be thread-safe.